# Is this legal in an Activity Diagram [UML]

Tags: uml, staruml

Particularly interested on the merge right after the decision. Can you have this?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to generate code with this? What does your tool say? 'UML as a sketch' doesn't have to be 'legal' to be useful. I don't see any definition of `num`, however. Did you mean `maximum` on the condition?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's legal, however:

1. You can combine merge and decision here into a single diamond (that's also legal and more elegant),
2. You can use loop here instead of your construct (that's even better in your specific example, however not necessarily answers your question).

Comment: Why not post a diagram?